# keras: theano.function is slower as compared to a model.predict()

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, theano

I have trained a recurrent neural network ( RNN ). For profiling the attention weights, I need 2 output from the trained network ( one at the final layer and one at an intermediate layer ).

Since `model.predict()`  gives its output from only the last layer, I wrote a theano function to fetch an output at both the intermediate layer and the final layer.

It works fine, but it is **almost 20 times slower** as compared to the **`model.predict()`**.

Can anybody help me to understand **why** the theano function is slower and **how** can I make it faster?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not get what you mean by theano.fun() ?

Comment: **Ref.** *(cit.)*: " ..., **I wrote a theano function to fetch an output** ...".
The point was *(cit.)*: " **What did your profiler tools efforts show up for each of the two** ...".
So?